# Segmentation fault на QSqlQuery::exec

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault

Есть такой код

```
QList<int> DBFacade::getBuildingIDs()
{
    // Подгрузка ID всех строений.
    QList<int> buildingIDs;
    QString query("SELECT TableBuildings.BuildID \n "
                  "FROM TableBuildings \n "
                      "LEFT JOIN BuildingTypes ON TableBuildings.BuildTypeID = BuildingTypes.TypeID \n "
                  "ORDER BY TableBuildings.Region ASC, CitiesAndCommunities.IsCity DESC, TableBuildings.CityOrCommID ASC");

    QSqlQuery sq;

    if (sq.exec(query)) // <- Вот тут выбрасывает
    {
        while (sq.next())
            buildingIDs << sq.value(0).toInt();
        qDebug() << "Notice:\t Loading building IDs";
    }
    else
        qDebug() << "Error:\t BuildID could not loaded: " << sq.lastError().text();
    return buildingIDs;
}
```

Странно то, что это выкидывает в режиме отладки. 
Думал, может ошибка в другом, но если убрать эту функцию, то тогда работает нормально. 
Не могу понять, что у меня тут такого, что могло вызвать ошибку сегментации

И да, у меня класс DBFacade работает во втором потоке. Перекидывал с помощью moveToThread. Может, это как-то связанно с ошибкой?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @AndrioSkur А я вижу. Сверху `bool QSqlQuery::exec(const QString &query)`

Comment: Попробуйте сконструировать объект так: <pre> QSqlQuery sq(query)</pre>  а вызов exec выкинуть. Еще можно отладчиком зайти в метод и посмотреть что там не так.

Comment: Где подключение к БД? `sq` у вас не связан с `QSqlDatabase`.

Comment: Окей, я сделал  так, хоть и немного радикально. Я снёс поток, теперь у меня всё выполняется в одном потоке (и подлагивает на запросах). И добавил БД в параметр запроса(хоть это и бессмысленно, ибо он берет default database (см. док.). ПОКА ЧТО проблема исчезла. Но я читал, что эта ошибка может вылезти когда угодно